# NoReverseMatch django error multiple URLs same method

Tags: python, django, django-templates

error message:

```
ExceptionType: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value: Reverse for 'darts.teams.views.expanded_details' with arguments '(u'RightFlights',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

in the template:

```
<a href="{{ lib.url(expanded_details, team.name) }}" class="btn btn-cog">Expanded Details</a>
```

in urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('darts.teams.views',
    url(r'^(?P<teamname>.*?)/expanded_details/$', 'team_details', {'expanded': True}, "expanded_details"),
    url(r'^(?P<teamname>.*?)/details/$', 'team_details', name="team_details"),

    url(r'^(?P<teamname>.*?)/add_player/$', 'team_add_player', name="team_add_player"),
    url(r'^(?P<teamname>.*?)/add_player/confirm/$', 'team_add_player',"team_add_player_confirm"),
)
```

The additional URLs in urls.py all render fine, but the 'expanded_details' one is throwing the error.

Why is this one different than the others?  Am I missing something blatant?

Comment: To me that looks like it is looking for expanded_details view instead of the named url.  What is that lib.url() you're using?  I always use {% url 'whatever' arg1 arg2 %}.

Comment: expanded_details is just a flag inside team_details.

lib.url is: def url(view_name, *args, **kwargs): from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse, NoReverseMatch return reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)

Comment: try {{ lib.url('expanded_details', team.name) }}

Answer (score 0):

*update*

The error says "Reverse for `'darts.teams.views.expanded_details'` failed", but it should be `'darts.teams.views.team_details'` or `'expanded_details'`. The first form is the path to view, the latter is the name of the named URL.
You could check the value of `expanded_details` inside the templatetag to ensure it is resolved to one of the correct values above, or follow slackjake's suggestion: use `'expanded_details'` (note the single quote) directly.

---

`(?P<teamname>.*?` is invalid, maybe you mean `(?P<teamname>.*?)`?
Also, what does `lib.url` do?

Comment: yea, typo on the closing paren.  I didn't copy and paste that part. sorry about that.


    def url(view_name, *args, **kwargs):
      from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse, NoReverseMatch
      return reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)